# How to check if a child exists in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase that has a node called users. The user gives a username and I want to check to see if that username already exists as a child of the users node. This is the code I am currently trying. The platform is android.

```
String myUsername = userNameInputET.getText().toString();
if(mUsersRef.child(myUsername) == null) {
//do stuff
} else {
//do other stuff
}
```

This code is not working, it always goes to the else, even if the child with the given username does not exist. What to do?

Comment: One way to do this is documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24824732/209103 (that answer is for Firebase's JavaScript SDK, but the logic is the same with any supported platform).

Answer (score 0):

```
    String myUsername="User";

    if (root.child(myUsername).getRoot() == null) {

    } else {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("user", "");
        root.updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: Could you describe why you have chosen this solution?

Comment: @Hassan Amjad, that seemed like a nice try, but when i ran that code, even if the "User" node didnt exist, it still gave me a URL. It was never null. i tried root.child(myUsername).getKey() too. But even that failed.any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

hello check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

```
// Test for the existence of certain keys within a DataSnapshot
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
    var b = snapshot.child("name").exists(); // true
    var c = snapshot.child("name/first").exists(); // true
    var d = snapshot.child("name/middle").exists(); // false
  });
```

Comment: I think he was looking for an answer that could be used with Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted two hours on this problem. Tried everything but none of the solutions worked. 
I used data read code of firebase onChildAdded to get the user data then determine it using if else condition.

In onCreate

```
mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mMessagesDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("user").child(root).child(id);
    attachDatabaseReadListener();
```

Listener method

```
    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
    if ( mChildEventListener == null) {
        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                User u = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                mUser=u.GetUser();
                mEmail=u.GetEmailId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"here"+mUser,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener( mChildEventListener);

    }
}
```

Condition check, It can be anything.

```
 if(mUser==null&&mEmail==null) {
      //do something here
  }
 else
 {
 //do nothing
 }
```

**Note: some time is required to execute on child added so add proper delay**
I have only one Node so this code worked perfectly for me. If any other solution or easier solution is available please let me know.

> if root node doesn't exists then also it will show null so keep that in mind before deploying application push root node.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you need to change your code to

```
String myUsername = userNameInputET.getText().toString();
if(mUsersRef.child(myUsername).getValue() == null) {
   //do stuff
} else {
   //do other stuff
}
```