# Make a query on Firebase database for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that there are many similar questions but no one has the answer I am looking for, all the questions I consulted have answers talking about childrenEvetListeners...

My question is so much simpler.  This my Firebase database: 
[image]

My question is: how can I make a query, checking if a user with the username="fofof" exists?

Comment: Related..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403068/how-to-check-if-a-child-exists-in-firebase

Comment: Yes but it has no answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hybrid structure, which complicates things. But if you are just looking for a match under `/users/-K....`, you can find the match with something like:

```
Query query = ref.child("users").orderByChild("User/username").equalTo("fofof");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fofof exists and is stored under key "+userSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

A few warnings about your current set-up though:

- you're storing users under a push ID. While push IDs are great for collections that don't have a natural key and that you want to store chronologically, it is better to store your users under the UID. So e.g. `/users/s5iu...`.
- you've nested the user information one level deeper than is necessary. While this works, I'd get rid of the `User` level in your tree.
- you have a user directly under `/users`, while others are stored one level deeper. Creating such a hybrid model is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank, as you know the push ID is inserted because i am using the push() function to create new nodes, i tried to avoid using push(), but in that case everytime a insert new user it overwrites the existing node and no new node is created, is there any way to create new nodes ( in my case for users) without using push() ??

Comment: `ref.child("users").child(userId).setValue(...)`