# firebase .on value not returning null when no data exists

Tags: firebase, angular, ionic2

I'm using firebase in angular/ionic 2 and I need to check if a value exists and to create it if it doesn't however firebase is not returning null as it states in the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) and my check does not run because of it.

```
subscribeToOffer(uid, offerID) {
    var path = 'users/' + uid + '/offers/' + offerID;

    this.rootRef.child(path).on('value', subscribed => {
        if (subscribed.val() !== null) {
            console.log('subscribed');
        } else {
            console.log('not subscribed');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't return null then what does it return? And are you sure the path is correct? Maybe add a sample of the data you are using in your question (as text, not an image please)

Comment: It doesn't return at all, nothing happens. The path is correct because when an offer exists it runs but when theres not it does nothing, I need something back to execute my else statement.

Comment: Did you try this: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/exists.html

Comment: Or looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824732/test-if-a-data-exist-in-firebase

Comment: Hi yeah tried, hasChild() and modified the path with no luck also tried exists() the same thing happens. I have a console.log(subscribed.val()); and it doesn't run when theres no child, it should return null. firebase version 241

Answer (score 0):

Here i have write a simple function for you that will return **true**  if offer id exist and **false** in other case.

```
subscribeToOffer(userId,offerId){
        var userRef = new Firebase(FBURL+'users');
        var userOfferRef = userRef.child(userId).child("offers");
        return userOfferRef.on("value", function(snap) {
          var offerIds = snap.val();
          return !!offerIds.hasOwnProperty(offerId);
        });
  };
```