# Firebase database updates - Unique Key Generation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently using push as it gives me a randomly ( or quazi-random ) unique identifier.

I'm in a scenario where I would prefer to use updates instead of pushes.

Is there anyway I can ask firebase to genarate a unique if for me?
Or would be be best to genarate on client side and if so how would I guard against updating a already existing key?

```
var updates = {};
updates['model/' + <i_need_new_unique_key_here>] = someVariable;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: When you create an item Firebase generates a unique key using the current time, so they're ordered chronologically. Is there a reason you can't generate an empty item, then push to it later?

Comment: It sounds like you want to check if a given key already exists. If that is the case, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824732/test-if-a-data-exist-in-firebase. For a more involved solution that enforces uniqueness on the server (by using security rules), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase

Comment: @BrettDeWoody i'm updating a lot at once, and all the data is interlinked so wold prefer to do it with one call

Comment: So you already have items created in Firebase? Or you want to push multiple items at once and have Firebase generate unique keys? You may need to update the question with some more details.

Comment: Does ```firebase.database().ref().key;``` make a round trip to google? It dosen't seem like it does. If f not the i Just loop though and create come keys for my updates.