# FireBase duplicate pushing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to avoid duplicate pushing into my firebase. The code is like this

```
const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('Titles');
                console.log(itemsRef)
                let poster = this.state.data.Poster
                let title = this.state.data.Title
                let movieTitle = {
                    title: title,
                    poster : poster,
                }
                itemsRef.push(movieTitle)
```

This is how I'm storing my data

[image]

UPDATE:
I solve this by making map loop and using index of.

```
   const pos = arr.map(function(e) { return e.title; });
                if (pos.indexOf(title) === -1){
                    itemsRef.push(movieTitle)
                } else {
                    console.log('Already exist')
                }
```

Comment: when you are using push it creates a timestamp id which is always unique. So on what criteria you don't want the duplicate data to exist ?

Comment: So ther is no way to do it?

Comment: Everything in firebase works on a link, so you can go through all the data and check if it exists or not

Comment: You will find here more info about the Firebase's push IDs: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: I tried to use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824732/test-if-a-data-exist-in-firebase but it didn't work for me ;/

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? can you give more detail?

Comment: As you can see in the image, i have two same objects in my database. I want to do something like this if object exist dont' push else push

Comment: Ok guys, I think i finally handle this. Thank's for all help.